# Is camelCode only common in object oriented languages?

Tags: programming-languages, camelcasing

Is it true, that there is a convention that purports, only to use camel code in object-oriented languages (as the W3C states in the link below)​​? If so why?

From the W3C:

> It is common, in object oriented languages, to use camel-case names.
>   You will often see names like someMethod(), instead of some_method().

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhSIa.png
http://w3schools.com/js/js_obj_intro.asp (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: I use(d) camel case with ActionScript 2, which was wasn't very close to being fully OOP compliant. For me it was easy to continue doing so because that is what I was taught and what I know to help make code readable rather than switching between camel case and some other format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, camel-case predates object-oriented programming. Programming languages have almost always had a limited character set from which variables and other object names could be composed. Because white-space is virtually never allowed and characters like "_" or "-" may not be, programmers have tried several conventions which make multi-word identifiers easier to read. Camel-case is just one convention.